# Can tourists view missile tests at the White Sands Missile Range?

Tags: usa, sightseeing, military, new-mexico, dunes

I [read](https://home.army.mil/wsmr/index.php/about) that the [White Sands Missile Range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Sands_Missile_Range) ([Gmaps](https://goo.gl/maps/7d4nwonjBaEKo91F9)) in New Mexico, USA conducts more than 3,000 tests annually. Can tourists view missile tests at the White Sands Missile Range?

Comment: The [museum](https://wsmrmuseum.com/faq-visiting/) is currently closed, and there is no access during missile testing anyway, because they set [road blocks](https://home.army.mil/wsmr/index.php/about/visitor-information) on the highways. They give the locations of the road blocks, perhaps you can find a vantage point. Good luck with that, mingling with all the international spies eager for a look.

Comment: If by view, you mean stand by the side of the road and hope to see a rocket trail, then yes.  But WTF do you think that random people would be allowed up close on an active military base in order to view to tests of weapon systems that have national security implications? You might as well also ask if you can pop into Area 51 for a picnic.

Comment: @PeterM It's not inconceivable to me that there may be some public showcases from time to time. Yes, I'm also looking at Area 51 https://www.vegassightseeing.com/area-51-tour/

Comment: The public showcase of missile launches *is* the WSMR museum.  However the Trinity site has an open day twice a year - but that has nothing to do with missile tests.

Comment: And your area 51 tour is just a drive in countryside near area 51.  It has nothing to do with the official area 51 itself.

Comment: In additional to the obvious secrecy and security concerns, there's also the question of safety. This is a *test* site, things may go awry, and you don't want to be there when something explodes where it shouldn't.

Comment: @littleadv doesn't prevent tourists from watching many rocket launches.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yes, they actually do. Missile ranges, bombing ranges, fire ranges - these are all restricted areas with limited access to civilians which is strictly controlled. You can't just wander in there, and if you do - you may very well never be able to leave, either because you're arrested or because a rocket explodes over you.

Comment: @littleadv Sounds like an answer.

Comment: @PeterM the page clearly states "Area 51 Top Secret Tour" though.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I can't tell if you're joking. What do you think that tour involves, exactly?

Comment: @ChrisH milking conspiracists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tourists can't view missile tests at the White Sands Missile Range, unless invited, [according to](https://www.reddit.com/r/travel/comments/10bxjpn/can_tourists_view_missile_tests_at_the_white) Reddit user [PurpleCactusFlower](https://www.reddit.com/u/PurpleCactusFlower),
who worked at the White Sands Missile Range:

> Not unless you know someone that works at WSMR to take you into the test center. I worked at WSMR in a different capacity for a while and they were always shutting roads down for tests. You can’t just spectate them. The missile museum. On post is worth a stop on the way to the national park though. And darth vaders helmet is there.

[Weather Vane](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane) mentioned some interesting pointers in the comment:

> The [museum](https://wsmrmuseum.com/faq-visiting/) is currently closed, and there is no access during missile testing anyway, because they set [road blocks](https://home.army.mil/wsmr/index.php/about/visitor-information) on the highways. They give the locations of the road blocks, perhaps you can find a vantage point. Goo